# generating sql statements from data returned in R by Postgresql

Tags: r, postgresql, rpostgresql

Fist I am executing following R commands which returns me a set of records from postgresql

```
col_qry <- paste("select column_name from table1",sep="")
rs_col <- dbSendQuery(r,col_qry)
temp_list <- fetch(rs_col,n=-1)
```

The Data returned is displayed is following format when printed in R using `print(temp_list)`

```
          column_name
1         col1
2         col2
3         col3
4         col4
```

Now based on this returned data I want to generate another sql statement which should be like this

```
copy (select "col1","col2","col3","col4" from table2 )
```

When I do this

```
tmp_cp <- paste("copy (select ",col_list,",","from table2",sep="")
```

and print this `tmp_cp` then instead of one `copy` statement bunch of `copy` statements are printed, one for each column name inside select like this

```
copy (select col1 from table2 )
copy (select col2 from table2 )
copy (select col3 from table2 )
copy (select col4 from table2 )
and so on...
```

**I want only one `copy` statement with all column names mentioned together, each quoted with `""` and separated by `,`**. How can I do that?

**UPDATE:** When I am using these statement

```
col_list <- toString(shQuote(temp_list$column_name))

tmp_cp <- paste("copy (select ",col_list,",","from table2",sep="")
```

then only one statement is generated but the column names are inside single quote instead of double quotes like this :

```
copy (select 'col1','col2','col3','col4' from table2 )
```

**NOTE:** I have mentioned 4 columns above but it is not that there are 4 columns only.columns can be many.For sake of explanation i have show 4 columns

Comment: I don't recall that SQL requires to put quotes around column names... I would assume that `tmp_cp <- paste(c(paste("copy (select"), paste(temp_list$column_name), "from table2)"), collapse = " ")
` should suffice

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
library(gsubfn)
sql <- fn$identity(
  "select `toString(shQuote(temp_list$column_name, 'cmd'))` from table2"
)
```

giving:

```
> sql
[1] "select \"col1\", \"col2\", \"col3\", \"col4\" from table2"

> cat(sql, "\n")
select "col1", "col2", "col3", "col4" from table2
```

This would work too and does not require any packages:

```
sprintf("select %s from table2", 
   toString(shQuote(temp_list$column_name, 'cmd')))
```

Comment: I want each of col1, col2 ... inside separate `""` like `"col1"`,`"col2"` and so on

Comment: but now as per your output there will be extra \ with each column name

Comment: I am not saying about double quotes.The output which you have shown above contains an extra \ (escape charater) associated with each quote.

Comment: No. There are no extra backslashes.  The backslashes you see are NOT part of the string.  I have added a `cat` at the end to show it.

Comment: when I am using `shQuote()` then I am getting single quote `'` instead of double quotes `"` around column names. I have updated my post above to depict my new statements under update section

Comment: I assume its system dependent (I'm using Windows).  I have added a second argument to force it to produce double quotes.

Answer (score 0):

Nested `paste` with the `collapse` argument:

```
paste("copy (select", paste(cols, collapse=", "), "from table2)")
```

If you want quoted column names:

```
paste("copy (select", paste(shQuote(cols, "cmd"), collapse=", "), "from table2)")
```